# Why use derivative of Sigmoid in neural network?

Tags: c#, neural-network

I created a simple perceptron with typical activation function (-1 or 1) and it seems to be working fine.
Then I read about sigmoid and its use for smoother transitions between the values but I always get 0.0 when using derivative which messes up the calculation. The sigmoid itself is fine, for smaller numbers its decimal and for larger it is again either -1 or 1.
What is the derivative good for then?
An example what I mean:

```
double actual (-1 or 1 when using the "old" function)
double AdjustWeight(int input1,input2, expected, actual)
{
   double error=expected-actual;   //when actual is derivative, is 0 for me, instead of -1 or 1
 ....
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Perceptron networks are single layer. Because of their non-continues activation function you can't use back-propagation algorithm on them, so they can't be multi-layer.
Instead Sigmoid function is a differentiable function and you can use back-propagation algorithm on them. In Perception you want to adjust weights you use :

```
W(new) = W(old) + a·(t-x)·y
```

when `a` is learning rate, `t` is target value, `x` is your input vector, and `y` is the output.

Instead when you want to use Sigmoid function, you have to use gradient-based algorithms. In these algorithms you adjust weights according to error derivative.

```
W(new) = W(old) - a·(dE/dW)
```

In a multi-layer network you can't use Perception algorithm Because it needs correct output and you don't know the correct output of a hidden neuron. So in multi-layer networks you have to use gradient-based algorithm and back-propagation for back propagating Error and `dE/dW`.

In a single layer neural network you can use either Perception or gradient-based algorithm. you can't tell witch on is better. Perception give you better grouping and gradient-based give you more noise resistance.

In gradient-based algorithms you use derivative of activation function in order to find dE/dW. if `Z` is total input of the neuron (Z = [sum on i] Wi·Xi) :

```
dE/dWi = Xi·(dE/dZ)

dE/dZ = -f'(Z)·(dE/dY)
```

In our case, because we used Sigmoid function, f'(Z) is Y(1-Y) for binary Sigmoid and 0.5(1-Y)(1+Y) for bipolar Sigmoid.

Normally we use following equation for error (cost function) :

```
E = 0.5(T-Y)^2
```

So our equations will transform to:

```
dE/dY = Y-T

dE/dZ = -0.5(1+Y)(1-Y)·(Y-T)

dE/dWi = - 0.5Xi·(1+Y)(1-Y)·(Y-T)

W(new) = W(old) + 0.5a·Xi·(1+Y)(1-Y)·(Y-T)
```

If you use following algorithm for updating weights I think your problems will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

The following is differentiation of Sigmoid function. "np.exp" is the same as; *The number e, a mathematical constant that is the base of the natural logarithm: the unique number whose natural logarithm is equal to one. It is approximately equal to 2.71828*. (Wikipedia)

```
# This is how mathematical the derivative of sigmoid is computed.
# Variables are only used as example for differentiation.
import numpy as np

x = 0.32

sigmoid = 1 / 1 + np.exp(-x)
differentiate = np.exp(-x) / (1+np.exp(-x)**2
differentiate_1 = np.exp(-x) - 1 / (1+np.exp(-x)**2
differentiate_2 = (1+np.exp(-x) / (1+np.exp(-x)**2) - (1/1+np.exp(-x))**2
differintiate_3 = sigmoid - sigmoid**2
sigmoid_prime = sigmoid * (1- sigmoid)
```

The transfer function, or sigmoid function, converts values in to probabilities
from 0 to 1. Sigmoid prime has a nice curve and converts values in range of 0 to 0.5.