# Multilayered neural network converging to infinity after barely 10 epochs with 0.1 learning rate

Tags: java, neural-network

So I am trying to design a multilayered neural network with 3 input neurons 3 hidden neurons and 1 output neuron.

I plan on making it learn the 3 bit xor pattern.  b1 xor b2 xor b3 kind of a table.
Right now I am trying to teach it  the following table.

```
0d,0d,0d    =>0d
0d,0d,1d    =>1d    
0d,1d,0d    =>1d
0d,1d,1d    =>0d
1d,1d,0d    =>0d
1d,1d,1d    =>1d
```

[image]

hidden[] is the weights between hidden layer and the output layer
input[] is the weights between input and hidden layer.

Ignore the D's

Here's the code and it converges after barely 10 epochs with 0.1 learning rate and the value of error is down to infinity :|

```
class neuron{
    double hidden[] = {1d,1d,1d};
    double input[][] = { {1d,1d,1d},{1d,1d,1d},{1d,1d,1d}};
    double learning = 0.1;
    double bias = 1d;

    public double[] react(double a,double b,double c){
        double h1 = a*input[0][0] + b*input[0][1] + c*input[0][2];
        double h2 = a*input[1][0] + b*input[1][1] + c*input[1][2];
        double h3 = a*input[2][0] + b*input[2][1] + c*input[2][2];
        //System.out.println(input[0][0]);
        double total[] = new double[4];
        total[0] = h1*hidden[0] + h2*hidden[1] + h3*hidden[2] + bias;
        total[1] = h1; total[2] = h2; total[3] = h3;
        return total;
    }

    public void learn(double a,double b, double c, double ideal){
        double actual[] = react(a,b,c);

        double error = ideal - actual[0];
        System.out.println(error);
        error *= learning;

        for( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
            hidden[i] += error * actual[i+1];
        bias += error;
        for( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ ){
            input[i][0] +=  error * actual[i+1] * a;
            input[i][1] +=  error * actual[i+1] * b;
            input[i][2] +=  error * actual[i+1] * c;
        }

        }
    }



public class multilayer{

        public static void main(String argz[]){
        neuron a = new neuron();
        for( int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
            a.learn(0d,0d,0d,0d);
            a.learn(0d,0d,1d,0d);   
            a.learn(0d,1d,0d,0d);
            a.learn(0d,1d,1d,0d);
            a.learn(1d,1d,0d,0d);
            a.learn(1d,1d,1d,1d);

        }
        System.out.println(a.react(0d,0d,0d)[0] >=0.5 ? 1 : 0);
        System.out.println(a.react(0d,0d,1d)[0]>=0.5 ? 1 : 0);
        System.out.println(a.react(0d,1d,0d)[0]>=0.5 ? 1 : 0);
        System.out.println(a.react(1d,1d,0d)[0]>=0.5 ? 1 : 0);
        System.out.println(a.react(0d,1d,1d)[0]>=0.5 ? 1 : 0);
        System.out.println(a.react(1d,1d,1d)[0]>=0.5 ? 1 : 0);
        }
}
```

I knocked off a hidden neuron and it still converges to infinity all the weights !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you should add a bias input for each of your hidden units too. Each non-input unit in an artificial neural network should have a bias input, it will help the unit to converge faster.

Second, you should change the weights in opposite direction (you should subtract error from weights). The main reason that you're converging to infinity is this. Because, the more bigger your weights are, the more bigger your error will be. By adding the error to the weight you're creating a chain reaction resulting weights (and error) converging to infinity.

Third, your learning algorithm is completely wrong :) specially the part that you calculate input weights regarding to error and their inputs.

In a multi-layer neural network, you should use error back propagation algorithm (EBP). This algorithm changes each weight regarding to its share in the final error. In order to find changing rate it uses derivative of output error. For more information about EBP check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15803984/why-use-derivative-of-sigmoid-in-neural-network) question.

Comment: Actually the use of bias inputs is not strictly necessary, though it is good to keep it a default to use them. Furthermore, error-backpropagation is not the only way to learn in a neural network. You might want to pre-learn with RBM learning.